# Bootstrap not working in Razor Pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

Bootstrap is working in my index page and other pages which are by default generate....But the folder i create inside pages and scaffold using crud on those pages bootstrap is not working.....I tried the same thing in asp.net core 2 mvc template and it works fine.

Here is my create view

```
@page
@model Memberships.Pages.Section_Page.CreateModel

@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>

<h4>Section</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger">
</div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Section.Title" class="control-label">
</label>
                <input asp-for="Section.Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Section.Title" class="text-
danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-
success" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Here is screenshot of my create view]

Comment: What specifically is not working ?

Comment: Using net core application, this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75099741/6280190

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not refreshing Bootstrap in your `<head>` so the page has no way of knowing you want to load it.

You need something along the lines of:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Since it is working on other pages, I assume you've referenced the library from your `_Layout.cshtml` (or some other shared layout). This layout won't be used however because you've explicitly told it *not* to load a layout:

```html
@{
   Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: Why would he set is layout to null?