# Bootstrap is not recognized in Razor page

Tags: razor, bootstrap-4

I just created a new project. I created a new Layout page and added Bootstrap like so:

```
head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
   
</head>
```

.net core with razor already came with bootstrap. below is the screen shot:

[image]

My page is simply doing CRUD operations and I tried to put a bootstrap icon and it did not work:

```
 <a class="btn btn-lg" asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.RecordId"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
```

All is see is blank space instead of the icon. I already looked at this URL and this is not the issue that I am having:

[Bootstrap not working in Razor Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508129/bootstrap-not-working-in-razor-pages/48530358)

Any hep will be greatly apprecaited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but, this is probably because you app can't read static files, your should try this in your startup.cs (or program.cs in net6 and above):

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```